# exclude transitive shaded dependency in maven

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

In my project i want to exclude `jackson-databind` from `tinkerpop`. It doesn't get excluded. I have open the pom.xml of tinkerpop https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/gremlin-shaded/pom.xml and I can see jackson is shaded. I have tried to exclude it:

`<groupId> org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson </groupId>` also this way `<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>`

Both approaches didn't worked out.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop.shaded.jackson</groupId> // com.fasterxml.jackson.core
                    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

How to exclude the shaded dependency ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `tinkerpop` shaded the other jar, and included the resulting classes into the final `tinkerpop` jar (which is usually be the case), then this other jar cannot be excluded because it has become part of `tinkerpop`.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this ? I got Vulas issues from the older version of jackson-databind which is included by tinkerpop and i want to resolve that issues by removing jackson-databind  from tinkerpop

Comment: So if jackson-databind is part of the tinkerpop jar, you can only use the whole jar or nothing. Of course, as tinkerpop seems to be on github, you might compile your own version of it, without the shaded jackson-databind jar.